# Comparing Dates with CriteriaQuery in hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate

In hibernate 4 i could do like

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(FlightData.class);

    // Restriction to match Departure Location, Arrival Location and ValidTill Date
    criteria.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("departureLocation", query.getDepartLoc()),
            Restrictions.eq("arrivalLocation", query.getArrivalLoc()),
            Restrictions.ge("validTill", query.getTravelDate())));
```

where validTill is of type LocalDate in java 8.
But with hibernate 5 if i do like

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<FlightData> cq = builder.createQuery(FlightData.class);


    Root<FlightData> root = cq.from(FlightData.class);

    cq.select(root).where(builder.and(
            builder.equal(root.get("departureLocation"), query.getDepartLoc()),
            builder.equal(root.get("arrivalLocation"), query.getArrivalLoc()),
            builder.ge(root.get("validTill"), query.getTravelDate())
            ));
```

then i get an error on builder.ge() method saying
type CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for arguments(Path,LocalDate).

my FlightData implimentation is

```
public class FlightData implements Serializable {

/** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6511441862178750017L;

/** The id serves as a primary key for the table */
private long id;

/** The flight number. */
private String flightNumber;

/** The departure location. */
private String departureLocation;

/** The arrival location. */
private String arrivalLocation;

/** The fare. */
private double fare;

/** The seat availability. */
private String seatAvailability;

/** The flight time. */
private String flightTime;

/** The flight duration. */
private String flightDuration;

/** The flight class. */
private String flightClass;

/** The Valid date. */
private LocalDate validTill;

/**
 * Gets the id.
 *
 * @return the id
 */
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * Sets the id.
 *
 * @param id the new id
 */
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


/**
 * Sets the flight number.
 *
 * @param flightNum the new flight number
 */
public void setFlightNumber(String flightNum) {
    flightNumber = flightNum;
}

/**
 * Gets the flight number.
 *
 * @return the flight number
 */
public String getFlightNumber() {
    return flightNumber;
}

/**
 * Sets the departure location.
 *
 * @param depLoc the new departure location
 */
public void setDepartureLocation(String depLoc) {
    departureLocation = depLoc;
}

/**
 * Gets the departure location.
 *
 * @return the departure location
 */
public String getDepartureLocation() {
    return departureLocation;
}

/**
 * Sets the arrival location.
 *
 * @param arrLoc the new arrival location
 */
public void setArrivalLocation(String arrLoc) {
    arrivalLocation = arrLoc;
}

/**
 * Gets the arrival location.
 *
 * @return the arrival location
 */
public String getArrivalLocation() {
    return arrivalLocation;
}

/**
 * Sets the seat availability.
 *
 * @param seatAvail the new seat availability
 */
public void setSeatAvailability(String seatAvail) {
    seatAvailability = seatAvail;
}

/**
 * Gets the seat availability.
 *
 * @return the seat availability
 */
public String getSeatAvailability() {
    return seatAvailability;
}

/**
 * Sets the fare.
 *
 * @param fare the new fare
 */
public void setFare(double fare) {
    this.fare = fare;
}

/**
 * Gets the fare.
 *
 * @return the fare
 */
public double getFare() {
    return fare;
}

/**
 * Sets the local date.
 *
 * @param date the new local date
 */
public void setValidTillDate(String date) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(date, "-");
    int day = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    int month = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    int year = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

    validTill = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
}

/**
 * Gets the local date.
 *
 * @return the local date
 */
public LocalDate getValidTillDate() {
    return validTill;
}

/**
 * Sets the flight duration.
 *
 * @param flightDur the new flight duration
 */
public void setFlightDuration(String flightDur) {
    flightDuration = flightDur;
}

/**
 * Gets the flight duration.
 *
 * @return the flight duration
 */
public String getFlightDuration() {
    return flightDuration;
}

/**
 * Sets the flight class.
 *
 * @param flightClass the new flight class
 */
public void setFlightClass(String flightClass) {
    this.flightClass = flightClass;

}

/**
 * Gets the flight class.
 *
 * @return the flight class
 */
public String getFlightClass() {
    return flightClass;
}

/**
 * Sets the flight time.
 *
 * @param flighttime the new flight time
 */
public void setFlightTime(String flighttime) {
    flightTime = flighttime;
}

/**
 * Gets the flight time.
 *
 * @return the flight time
 */
public String getFlightTime() {
    return flightTime;
}
```

}

Any suggestions on how to compare LocalDate with hibernate 5 using Criteria.

Comment: what is the error? also add the the FlightData entity impl

Answer (score 0):

If you started using Hibernate 5, then i would suggest adding this dependency to your classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This will allow Hibernate to treat those types as Basic types.

Date and Time API will be standardized in the next version of JPA.
Until then workarounds like using that library or implementing custom `@Converter` (see this great article on the subject: [converters](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/)) is a necessity.